# What blocks can I place next to cacti?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just found out I can place a water source next to a cactus and it won't destroy the cactus. I would also like a block next to the cactus, but I have no idea what transparent and non-transparent blocks I can place without breaking the cactus. Could someone help me find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon testing, the following blocks can be placed next to a Cactus without breaking it.

- Air
- Plants
- Saplings (on tree growth, however, the Cactus drops)
- Rails
- Mushrooms
- Lever
- Buttons
- Torch
- Redstone Torch
- Snow layer
- Vines
- Lily Pad
- Tripwire Hook
- Carpet
- End Rod
- Fire
- Painting
- Redstone
- Chorus Plant
- Chorus Flower
- String
- Seeds
- Wheat
- Carrot
- Potato
- Pumpkin Stem
- Melon Stem
- Sugar Cane
- Cocoa Beans
- Water
- Nether Wart
- Redstone Repeater
- Redstone Comparator
- Item Frame
- Flower Pot
- Skulls
- Beetroot
- Structure Void
- Sea Pickles